# Suppose that $X_n$ are integer valued, and $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How can we show that $m+\frac{1}{2}$ is a continuity point of the distribution function of $X$, if $m$ is an integer? Do I need to show that $X$ is also integer valued?